# Why can't I link contacts? (Moto G Stylus)

Tags: contacts

I just started to use a Moto G Stylus. I copied my contacts over, and several contacts are linked (like Gmail, Signal, WhatsApp, Exchange, etc.). This is how I had it on my previous phone and is as it should be.

However, I can't create new links -- neither completely new links, nor adding contacts to already linked contacts. The only things I can do is display the links of already linked contacts and unlink them.

Does anybody know what I could do to be able to link contacts? Is this a limitation of this specific dialer?

The odd thing is that the Verizon help for this phone mentions the "Link" feature (https://www.verizon.com/support/knowledge-base-230168/), but the Motorola help page for the Contact app doesn't (https://support.motorola.com/us/en/solution/MS149789). I got my phone through Google Fi, FWIW.

(Note that I'm not talking about merging contacts. Merging only works within a given account; linking contacts is provided specifically to be able to link contacts from different accounts into a single entry in the contact list.)

Comment: Try a different contact app?

Comment: @beeshyams: That's what I'm doing. So far I've tried Simpler Caller ID and Drupe, and neither has the link feature. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not particularly.....

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I have found out that the dialer of this phone really can't link contacts. What a bummer... I thought this was a basic functionality of all but the most basic phones. (Well, maybe it is, and this phone is just one of the most basic ones.)

In any case, be prepared to add a 3rd party dialer to the bill if you're thinking of buying this phone from anywhere but Verizon.

From [Motorola](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/moto-g-stylus-moto-g-pro/I-can-t-link-contacts/m-p/5055303):

> The :Link" feature that you've mentioned is only available for Verizon specific phones, so a Moto G Stylus that is purchased from Verizon would work with that feature.